# Jar before jre - java classpath

Tags: java, classpath

is there a way to run java and tell it to use a certain jar higher in the classpath than the jre?

I know it is possible in eclipse run configuration, but I want it to work using java from command line.

The reason is that there is a class that is loaded from the jre and I wanted a different version that should have been loaded from an external jar. I saw this was the case using -verbose.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this Java arg

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:my.jar
```